# Wordpress how to use a second form that only searches for posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, query-string, query-variables

I have two forms on my wordpress site, `search.blade.php` and `blog-search.blade.php`.

`search.blade.php` is in the header of the site, and searches all content types.

`blog-search.blade.php` is meant to only search post types.

I'm using the following code to have it search for only blog posts:

```
    function searchfilter($query) {
 
    if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'post');
    }
 
return $query;
}
 
add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');
```

Understandably, this applies to both search.blade.php AND blog-search.blade.php, but I only want it to apply to blog-search.

I think that if I added a conditional to check for the value of a hidden input that only exists on blog-search, I could get it to work, but I don't know how to do that.

Here's my **blog-search.blade.php** code:

```
<form action="{{ get_bloginfo('url') }}" method="GET" class="blog-search-form">
    <input type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search the blog...">
    <input type="hidden" name="search-type" value="normal" />
    <span class="icon-search"></span>
</form>
```

Is there a way I could implement something like:

```
 function searchfilter($query) {
 
    if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() && INPUT TYPE == HIDDEN ) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'post');
    }
    ...
```

So that only the blog-search searches through posts, and my main search works as usual? I tried [implementing this](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-use-multiple-search-forms-in-wordpress/), with no luck, so I'm thinking a conditional could help.

search.blade.php, just in case:

```
<form action="{{ get_bloginfo('url') }}" method="GET" class="search-form">
    <input type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search the site">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set this up in multiple ways. I personally always use ajax method to query a database, but if you would like to use `query_vars` method as you're already thinking about it and suggesting it in your question, then you could do something like this:

So this would be your html form:

```html
<form method="GET">
    <input type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search the blog...">
    <input type="hidden" name="onlyblog" id="onlyblog" value="yes" />
    <span class="icon-search"></span>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

then on the `php` side, your conditional check would for `onlyblog` value like so:

```php
function searchfilter($query) {

$query_type = isset($_GET['onlyblog']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['onlyblog']) : "";
 
    if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() && !empty($query_type) && 'yes' == $query_type) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'post');
    }
 
return $query;
}
```

Let me know if you were able to get it to work!

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was able to get it to work - thanks! Oddly enough, there was something on one version of my site that was causing the issue - when I tried your code on a Development environment it worked perfectly.