# Woocommerce how to display relevant tags under category title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tags, wordpress-theming

I want to display meta tags under each category title. I can see there is this code to display product tag lists for each product, but what I really want is product tags for each category and then display it under the category title in the page.

```php
<?php

global $product;

?>

<div class="product-tags">

<?php 

echo wc_get_product_tag_list( $product->get_id(), ', ' ); 

?>

</div>
```

Example screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you already know/have the category name (i.e 'Coffee Equipment'), so you could use that to get the relevant tags, but in order to do so, we'll create a function in the `functions.php` of your active theme, like so:

**The following code goes to your `functions.php` file of your active theme:**

```php
function your_theme_get_tags_based_on_cat($cat_name)
{

  $cat_id = get_cat_ID($cat_name);

  $tag_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'tax_query'      => array(
      array(
          'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
          'field'         => 'term_id', 
          'terms'         => $cat_id,
          'operator'      => 'IN' 
        )
      )
  ));

  $all_tags = array();

  while ($tag_query->have_posts()) {
    $tag_query->the_post();
    $producttags = get_the_tags();
    if ($producttags) {
      foreach ((array)$producttags as $tag_obj) {
        $all_tags[] = $tag_obj->term_id . '-' . $tag_obj->name;
      }
    }
  };

  $tags_array = array_unique($all_tags);

  $new_array = array_map(function ($val) {
    return explode("-", $val);
  }, $tags_array);

  return new_array;
}
```

The function above will return an associative array containing `tag id` and `tag name` of the corresponding tags of your **PRODUCT** category.

> Side Note:
> if you need to use it for the blog posts of your wordpress site, then you could change/modify the query by swapping `'post_type' => 'product'` argument with `'post_type' => 'posts'`.  So your query for blog posts would be something like this:
>
> `$blog_tag_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post','post_status'    =>'publish','cat'=>$cat_id,'posts_per_page'=>-1));`
>
> If you decide to use it for your blog posts, also remember to change the `get_term_link((int)$tag[0], 'product_tag')` with `get_term_link((int)$tag[0], 'post_tag')` in your template.

> Now you have a magical function :) that you can use anywhere that you need a list of tags for a specific category!

So let's use our function in your page template to populate the corresponding tags for the current category, like so:

```php
$cat_name = 'Coffee Equipment';

$tags_array = your_theme_get_tags_based_on_cat($cat_name);

foreach ($tags_array as $tag) 
{
echo '<a class="item" href="' . get_term_link((int)$tag[0], 'product_tag') . '">' . $tag[1] . '</a>';
};
```

Just tested and it works seamlessly fine! Feel free to customize it as needed on your `html template/markup`.

Comment: I wonder @Ruvee as I am a wordpress novice. There is one other thing I like to ask you. My client asked to create some filters which are like an accordian and depending on the category, it will display the correct filters. This link is a good example where if you switch categories like from top menu "Coffee", "Cups" etc, the filters on the left hand side changes: https://www.categoricallycoffee.co.uk/collections/coffees. You wouldn't know if there is a suitable free plugin that can handle this or will it have to be through code?

Comment: Thanks! Honestly I write my own filters and pretty much everything i need for my clients, so i don't really use any plugin(s), therefore i don't know any plugin(s) to recommend, but i'd be happy to try to help if you have any question(s) regarding your code here on SO!

Comment: If you don't mind, I want to know how to create different filters based on categories of product. Let me give you examples...

Comment: So this is the live website: https://balancecoffee.co.uk/ and if you don't mind going to one of the shop pages. The instructions my client has given is: "remove green column from Balance website and replace with filters like this page: https://www.categoricallycoffee.co.uk/collections/coffees"

Comment: So then you can see on their website, when you switch to different category of products, the filter changes. Now he doesn't have as many filters. For example for his coffee, he can have a price filter, reviews filter, bag size filter and grind size filter. And then when move to another category product, he will have price and reviews filter and then any other variation which is linked to that category product if that makes sense. But I don't know where to start. I'm more a front end than back end developer so not sure how to do this. Any help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Good then, at least you're programmer:) There are certain keywords that wordpress engine knows about and called `query_vars`! So when these `query_vars` exist in the url, wordpress would recognize them and query the database accordingly! So these `query_vars` would help you create what you're looking for. I've explained about filtering based on `query_vars`. [Here's a link on query vars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67542594/15040627). Also if you search for `query_vars` you'll find useful materials to write your filters!